# Anaconda, conda, pip и pythonnet, как правильно настроить-собрать?

Tags: python-3.6, pip, anaconda, nuget, pythonnet

Имеется следующая конфигурация.

- Windows 8.1
- Anaconda 5.2.0 + Python 3.6.5
- Pythonnet 2.3.0

Вся эта конфигурация установлена долгими бессонными ночами методом подбора под последний пакет `Pythonnet 2.3.0`, в другой связке эта версия не работает.

В свою очередь версия `Pythonnet 2.3.0` навязана отсутствием NuGet пакета под версию `Pythonnet 2.4.0`.

Что соответственно вызывает проблемы, например `pip` все время ругается, что он не обновлен. `Conda` не все пакеты видит, видимо из за старой версии. Не доступна работа с `Python 3.7`

Теперь собственно вопрос:

1. Как так получается что [тут](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/) и [тут](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) видно что доступна версия 2.4.0
   (и поддерживается Python 3.7) а NuGet пакета нету, а какой смысл
   тогда этой версии без пакета под студию?
2. Что будет если обновить только pip, не сломает ли он другие зависимости?
3. Где взять библиотеки dll если нет пакета NuGet, компилировать самому, где/как узнать почему нет пакета, это нормально?

> P.S. Не нужно Пасленовых, я просто не могу понять почему так.

Comment: Они разве не в разные стороны работают?

Comment: @Qwertiy кто они? Pythonnet для питона под windows и для mono? Так и для mono не вижу версии 2.4.0. Зачем вообще модуль для питона если он не будет работать с .NET?

Comment: Ты что из чего пытаешься запустить? Питон из .net или .net из питона?

Comment: @Qwertiy логично же все, если нужен NuGet пакет, то естественно питон из .NET а иначе я бы обошелся одним модулем установленным в питоне, который как раз доступен включая новую версию.